# HTML manually built datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to build an HTML datepicker using the code below, I am not using jquery because I am reading the returned value to a classic asp page.

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% Response.Expires = 0 %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Intranet.css">
<META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0">
<SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersJS LANGUAGE=javascript>
<!--

function window_onload() {

    mydate= new Date()
    theMonth.selectedIndex = mydate.getMonth();
    theYear.selectedIndex = mydate.getYear()-1940;
    window.returnValue = (mydate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + mydate.getDate() + "/" + mydate.getYear();
    display_calendar();
}

function navigateMonth(direction) {
    if (direction==1)
        if (theMonth.selectedIndex==11)
            {
            theMonth.selectedIndex = 0;
            theYear.selectedIndex = theYear.selectedIndex + 1;
            }
        else
            theMonth.selectedIndex = theMonth.selectedIndex + 1;
    else
        if (theMonth.selectedIndex==0)
            {
            theMonth.selectedIndex = 11;
            theYear.selectedIndex = theYear.selectedIndex - 1;
            }
        else
            theMonth.selectedIndex = theMonth.selectedIndex - 1;
    display_calendar();
}

function display_calendar() {

    for(i=0;i<42;i++) thisCell(i).innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

    d = new Date(theYear.value, theMonth.value, 1)
    d_next = new Date(theYear.value, theMonth.value, 1)
    currdate = new Number(theMonth.value)

    if (currdate == 3 && theYear.value == 2011)
    {
        d_next = new Date(2011, 4, 2);

        if (d.getDate() != 1){ 
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); 
        }
        else {
        d_next.setDate(d_next.getDate() - 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        d_next.setMonth(currdate+1);
    }

    if (currdate==3 && theYear.value==2005)
    {
        d = new Date(theYear.value, 3, 1, 23, 59, 00)
        d_next = new Date(theYear.value, 4, 1, 23, 59, 00)
        currdate = new Number(theMonth.value)
    }

    for(i=d.getDay();i<Math.round((d_next-d)/86400000+d.getDay());i++) 
    {
        if (thisCell(i)) 
        {
            thisCell(i).innerHTML = "<p style='CURSOR:hand' onclick=selectDate('" + (currdate+1) + "/" + (i-d.getDay()+1) + "/" + theYear.value + "')>" + (i-d.getDay()+1) + "</P>";
        }
    }
}

function theYear_onchange() {
    display_calendar();
}

function theMonth_onchange() {
    display_calendar();
}

function selectDate(s) {
    //alert(s);
    //s=Date.parse(s);
    //alert(s);
    window.returnValue = s;
    window.close();
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>

<TITLE>Select Date</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<body Class ="DialogBody"  LANGUAGE=javascript onload="return window_onload()">  
<TABLE cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=1 border=1 align=center>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap colSpan=5 align=center>
  <input onclick="navigateMonth(-1)" type="Button" Value="< " id=Button1 name=Button1><SELECT id=theYear size=1 name=theYear LANGUAGE=javascript onchange="return theYear_onchange()"> 
  <% For i =1940 to Year(Now) + 20 %> 

    <OPTION value=<%=i%> selected><%=i%></OPTION>   

  <%Next%>
  </SELECT>

 <!-- <OPTION value=1999>1999</OPTION><OPTION 
  value=2000>2000</OPTION><OPTION value=2001>2001</OPTION><OPTION 
  value=2002>2002</OPTION><OPTION value=2003>2003</OPTION><OPTION 
  value=2004>2004</OPTION><OPTION value=2005>2005</OPTION><OPTION 
  value=2006>2006</OPTION><OPTION value=2007>2007</OPTION><OPTION 
  value=2008>2008</OPTION><OPTION value=2009>2009</OPTION><OPTION 
  value=2010>2010</OPTION><OPTION value=2011>2011</OPTION><OPTION 
  value=2012>2012</OPTION>-->

  <SELECT id=theMonth size=1 name=theMonth LANGUAGE=javascript onchange="return theMonth_onchange()"> 
  <OPTION value=0 selected>January</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=1>February</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=2>March</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=3>April</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=4>May</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=5>June</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=6>July</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=7>August</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=8>September</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=9>October</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=10>November</OPTION>
  <OPTION value=11>December</OPTION></SELECT><input onclick="navigateMonth(1)" type="Button" Value=" >" id=Button1 name=Button1>
    </TD>
    <TD noWrap colSpan=2 align=center><input onclick="selectDate('')" type="Button" Value="Clear" id=Button1 name=Button1></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap><STRONG>&nbsp;Sun </STRONG></TD>
    <TD noWrap><STRONG>&nbsp;Mon </STRONG></TD>
    <TD noWrap><STRONG>&nbsp;Tue </STRONG></TD>
    <TD noWrap><STRONG>&nbsp;Wed </STRONG></TD>
    <TD noWrap><STRONG>&nbsp;Thu </STRONG></TD>
    <TD noWrap><STRONG>&nbsp;Fri </STRONG></TD>
    <TD noWrap><STRONG>&nbsp;Sat </STRONG></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell></SPAN></TD>
    <TD noWrap><SPAN id=thisCell LANGUAGE=javascript onclick="alert(this.sourceIndex)"></SPAN></TD></TR>
    </TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

i get the sketch of the table but it seems that there is a problem with the "thiscell" span.

What might be the problem?

Comment: What browser are your users using? Can you not use the `HTML 5` datepicker, this would save you a lot of time.

Comment: how does it manifest? what happens, what is expected?

Comment: I think one of the problems is that not many browsers support HTML 3.2 any more. Also, multiple ids is an error, even in HTML 3.2. And what's with the `language` attribute?

Comment: Provide a proper problem description and associated errors thrown. Using jQuery has nothing to do what what server language or framework you use

Comment: _“I am not using jquery because I am reading the returned value to a classic asp page”_ – that’s like saying, “I am not using a fork to eat my dinner, because the plate is blue.”

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure since I don't have the equipment to run a page written with VBScript, but as far as I can see you have written this.

```
<SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersJS LANGUAGE=javascript>
<!--
...
function selectDate(s) {
    //alert(s);
    //s=Date.parse(s);
    //alert(s);
    window.returnValue = s;
    window.close();
}

//-->
```

As you can directly with the syntax highlighting this site uses, you have commented out your complete script section. The `<!--` at the beginning of the script is meant for old browsers to make them ignore the JavaScript they may not support. Nowadays almost every browser support JavaScript so things like that aren't needed any more, but there are some people who wish to block JavaScript on purpose.

Because of this practice, W3Schools suggests to write your javascript code like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var i = 10;
if (i < 5) {
  // some code
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Again. As you can see at the syntax highlighting. Now the JavaScript code isn't commented out. Also, ASP is kind of outdated now. It is better to use ASPX with .NET and C#. It also may be a good idea to check the settings of your IIS server.

*EDIT*

I took a closer look at the code

```
for(i=0;i<42;i++) thisCell(i).innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

d = new Date(theYear.value, theMonth.value, 1)
d_next = new Date(theYear.value, theMonth.value, 1)
currdate = new Number(theMonth.value)
```

Where do you get the thisCell object? There is no you did not assign a value to this object when you used it i think. There are a few ways in which you can achieve this. For instance, if you are using jQuery.

```
var thisCell = $("#thisCell");
```

Or if you are using standard JavaScript

```
var thisCell = document.getElementById("thisCell");
```

The latter will work always. For the jQuery version you need to import jQuery first.

The function getElementById however is supposed to return only one element I think. The ID attribute is not supposed to have the same value assigned to multiple tags. Change every id attribute to a class attribute. After you have done that you can access the elements like this.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("thisCell");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello, my code works fine on IE, why doesnt it work fork chrome?

Comment: That is propably because IE does not care that much about web standards. In effect, there are a lot of webpages hwo are developed for IE and will not work on other browersers.  Also the generator you use is pretty old. I would consider updating to a newer version of visual studio. The express version of visual studio is free if you register.